# Jquery extend deep copy issue

Tags: jquery

An external partner has developed a jquery plugin for us.
I wanted to reset some the settings and to my suprise it wasn't working.

I did some debug and came to the following results:

I've noticed that they used the deep copy of $.extend

```js
var t = '{"config":{"filters":{"filtersPerCarousel":2,"sliders":[{"machineName":"brightness","filter":"brightness","range":100,"step":5,"value":0,"translationKey":"filter.slider.brightness"},{"machineName":"contrast","filter":"contrast","range":100,"step":5,"value":0,"translationKey":"filter.slider.contrast"}],"presets":[{"machineName":"original","filters":[],"previewImage":"/images/filters/original.png","translationKey":"filter.original"},{"machineName":"blackwhite","filters":[{"filter":"saturation","settings":[-100]}],"previewImage":"/images/filters/blackwhite.png","translationKey":"filter.blackwhite"},{"machineName":"sepia","filters":[{"filter":"greyscale","settings":[]},{"filter":"sepia","settings":[60]}],"previewImage":"/images/filters/sepia.png","translationKey":"filter.sepia"}]}}}';
var o = '{"config":{"filters":{"sliders":[],"presets":[]}}}';
settings = $.extend(true, {}, jQuery.parseJSON(t), jQuery.parseJSON(o));
console.log(settings.config);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When deep copy isset to true my config.sliders is not modified and keeps the original state.

The config is modified when i remove the deep copy and just use the $.extend

```js
var t = '{"config":{"filters":{"filtersPerCarousel":2,"sliders":[{"machineName":"brightness","filter":"brightness","range":100,"step":5,"value":0,"translationKey":"filter.slider.brightness"},{"machineName":"contrast","filter":"contrast","range":100,"step":5,"value":0,"translationKey":"filter.slider.contrast"}],"presets":[{"machineName":"original","filters":[],"previewImage":"/images/filters/original.png","translationKey":"filter.original"},{"machineName":"blackwhite","filters":[{"filter":"saturation","settings":[-100]}],"previewImage":"/images/filters/blackwhite.png","translationKey":"filter.blackwhite"},{"machineName":"sepia","filters":[{"filter":"greyscale","settings":[]},{"filter":"sepia","settings":[60]}],"previewImage":"/images/filters/sepia.png","translationKey":"filter.sepia"}]}}}';
var o = '{"config":{"filters":{"sliders":[],"presets":[]}}}';
settings = $.extend({}, jQuery.parseJSON(t), jQuery.parseJSON(o));
console.log(settings);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Why is my object modified with deep copy not set and why isn't it modified with deep copy? 
It would make more sense that this was the other way around?

The jquery version is 1.9.1, but i've tested this on multiple version and they all gave the same result.

Comment: You have to set deep copy to `true` for deep copying; that is per design. What is your concern here? What is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/).

jQuery Extend MERGES all objects passed to it, it does not override the objects. If you pass a filled object and an empty one, it merges and gets all data from both. For it to get all internal data, you need to set deep copy to true.

If you need to reset some of the values, you can just manually set them

```js
var t = '{"config":{"filters":{"filtersPerCarousel":2,"sliders":[{"machineName":"brightness","filter":"brightness","range":100,"step":5,"value":0,"translationKey":"filter.slider.brightness"},{"machineName":"contrast","filter":"contrast","range":100,"step":5,"value":0,"translationKey":"filter.slider.contrast"}],"presets":[{"machineName":"original","filters":[],"previewImage":"/images/filters/original.png","translationKey":"filter.original"},{"machineName":"blackwhite","filters":[{"filter":"saturation","settings":[-100]}],"previewImage":"/images/filters/blackwhite.png","translationKey":"filter.blackwhite"},{"machineName":"sepia","filters":[{"filter":"greyscale","settings":[]},{"filter":"sepia","settings":[60]}],"previewImage":"/images/filters/sepia.png","translationKey":"filter.sepia"}]}}}';

settings = jQuery.parseJSON(t);

settings.config.filters.sliders = [];
settings.config.filters.presets = [];

console.log(settings);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```